# Google Chrome asked for my Carbonite password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, carbonite

Google Chrome recently asked for password access to my Carbonite backup account.  How can I be sure it didn't get it and/or block it from future access?

Comment: Change your password...?

Comment: Eh? If you logged into Carbonite and have Chrome set to save passwords, this is news because???

Answer (score 1):

You can be save, if you don't allow google to save passwords/not to ask you. chrome won't save passwords without your permission. You can disable this offer by opening the password-manager:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings.
4. Adjust your password settings in the "Passwords and forms" section:

Now you can change the button at the field `Passwords` and "untick" the *Offer to save passwords I enter on the web*.

[image]

If you want to be save, that your password wasn't saved by chrome, you can click on the <kbd>Manage save passwords</kbd> - button. Now you should see this menu where you can check the saved passwords. If it is there, and If you want to remove it, just click on the <kbd>X</kbd> - icon on the right of the password and click <kbd>Done</kbd> - button:

[image]

And don't worry. Chrome **doesn't** save passwords without your permission.